# Why do alias names the same as the column names get dropped when stored as a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, ssms, sql-view

I can write this in an SSMS query tab:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ISBN AS ISBN, Title AS Title
FROM dbo.tBook
ORDER BY Title, ISBN
```

If I write it as a Create View:

```
CREATE VIEW vBook1 
AS
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ISBN AS ISBN, Title AS Title
    FROM dbo.tBook
    ORDER BY Title, ISBN
```

SSMS will create the view ***but*** it drops the aliases, I assume because the aliases are the same as the table columns?

Of course, I can use different aliases and that gets saved in the view:

```
CREATE VIEW vBook1 
AS
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ISBN AS ISBNx, Title AS Titlex
    FROM dbo.tBook
    ORDER BY Title, ISBN
```

I want to alias the names in the stored view using the original names to maintain some consistency, but if the underlying table column names do change, the users of the view won't have to edit their code.

Comment: AFAIK, the only columns available in a view are the ones selected by the underlying query.  So, your second approach is one way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by: *SSMS will create the view but it drops the aliases*? What are the titles of the columns of the view after you run the `CREATE VIEW` command?

Comment: @GMB The AS clauses are dropped by the view designer and they don't get stored by SQL Server when you execute a CREATE view statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long for a comment.  You say:

> if the underlying table column names do change, the users of the view won't have to edit their code

Well that is sort of true.  If the underlying column names change, then the view will be invalidated.  The code will no longer work.  You will need to recreate the view anyway.

If you want to ensure the column names, you can create the view *explicitly* with the column names:

```
Create view vBook1 (ISBN, Title) AS
    SELECT ISBN, Title
    FROM dbo.tBook;
```

I am not generally a really big fan of this approach -- it can wreak havoc when adding or re-arranging column names for the view.  But you might appreciate it.

Note that I removed the `ORDER BY` and `TOP 100 PERCENT`.  These are hacks to get the `ORDER BY` accepted by the SQL Server compiler.  That doesn't mean that the view is guaranteed to be in any particular order.

This is quite explicitly explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **Important**
>
> The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the TOP or OFFSET clause in the view definition. **The ORDER BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried**, unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.

Comment: "You will need to recreate the view anyway." - I never said I wouldn't have to do that. I said that the users of the view would have to edit their code. So we have an opportunity for error because when editing the view I would have to remember to add the aliases for the original column name(s).

Comment: @nicomp . . . Not if you define the *view* with the explicit column names.  But if you have to redefine the view anyway, that introduces the possibility of errors.  Happily, renaming columns is a very infrequent occurrence on well-designed databases.

Comment: Your syntax seems to have the same problem as mine: when I execute your script, with the original column names in the parens, the AS clauses are dropped when I open the view in the designer. When I edit your script to use kludged up column names in the parens, the AS clauses persist when I open the view designer.

Comment: @nicomp . . . The `as` assignments are irrelevant if the names are provided as part of the definition of the view.

Comment: @nicomp, don't use the SSMS view designer. Use an SSMS query window to have full control over the view DDL.

Comment: @DanGuzman Doesn't matter, when the view is stored in the db it drops the AS assignments.

Comment: @nicomp, the view text won't be altered when run form a query window. Run `EXEC sp_helptext 'vBook1';` to verify. The view designer might change the code though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faulty premise in your question:

> I want to alias the names in the stored view using the original names to maintain some consistency, but if the underlying table column names do change, the users of the view won't have to edit their code.

A view is defined using an SQL query; the columns it references are referenced by name, just like in any other SQL query. If the underlying columns change, the view will need to be updated - and when it is, you can add, change, or remove whatever aliases you need to make it look how other code expects.

---

Let's define a really simple table, and a view which aliases the column name:

```
Create Table Foo ( Bar int )

Create View FooView as
    Select Bar as ViewBar
    From Foo

Select * From FooView
```

So far, so good. Now let's rename the underlying column:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Foo.Bar', 'NewBar', 'COLUMN'

Select * From FooView
```

We get an error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FooView, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 10]
Invalid column name 'Bar'.
Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Could not use view or function 'FooView' because of binding errors.
```

The alias didn't stop the view breaking, it still needs to be fixed; we keep the *alias* the same, but change the *column name*:

```
Alter View FooView as
    Select NewBar as ViewBar
    From Foo

Select * From FooView
```

Now it works again, and queries referencing the view will see the column name they expected.

---

The process would be **exactly the same** if we didn't alias the column in the original view:

```
Create Table Foo ( Bar int )

Create View FooView as
    Select Bar
    From Foo

Select * From FooView
```

OK

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Foo.Bar', 'NewBar', 'COLUMN'

Select * From FooView
```

As before, we get an error.

So as before, we use an alias in the view to keep the column name in the view the same as it was:

```
Alter View FooView as
    Select NewBar as Bar
    From Foo

Select * From FooView
```

Now everything is OK again, *and code using the view doesn't have to change*.

So adding an alias in the original view wouldn't have helped us in any way; it makes no difference to the result.